# How do I ask a SQL Server index (sic) to show me its (sic) index data rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

This is a very specific question; it is about the data rows directly associated with a SQL Server index.

Searching I found many articles but nothing that answers this question.

```
scenario

database      visitors

schema  
           dbo.Visitor  table  
PK     sin      numbers  
       Fname    characters  
       Lname    characters  
       Birth    yyyyMMdd  
       Visit    yyyyMMddHHmm  

index    IX_visitors_visit
```

Each row of index data consists of `<sin, Visit>`

Goal:  for a given sin, view ALL of the rows in the index for that specific sin.

Please note, I do not want to view the associated rows in the `dbo.Visitor` table

Answer (score 0):

Start from [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259#indexes-and-constraints). This explains the structure of Clustered and Non-Clustered Indexes.

Indexes are fundamentally used to speed up retrieval of data from a table. A Clustered Index does not exist separately from the table - it is the data rows stored in index order.  A Non-Clustered Index is a copy of the index key values PLUS a pointer to the data row in the table that contains that key value.

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve - you would normally query the table with a filter to define the rows that you need, specifying the columns that you want returned for those rows and in a requested order. This may or may not use the index you have specified - the Query Engine will determine that when it produces the optimum Query Plan.

If you want to see exactly what is in the index then you'd need to look at the index pages themselves, or just infer it from the index definition - i.e. in your case the index would contain ALL the rows of the table but only the columns `sin` and `Visit` plus an additional column that is used to map back to the corresponding row in the table.

If your query specifies a given `sin` and you want ONLY the `Visit` column as well in your result set then you'd specify:

```
SELECT sin, Visit FROM dbo.Visitor WHERE sin = xxxxxxx
```

This would give you all the rows where `sin = xxxxxxx` and return the `sin` and `Visit` columns.   It is likely that it would use your index to retrieve this results set as it is likely to use fewer reads to do so (depends on the number of rows in your table).

If however you also want the `Birth` column in your results you would have a query like:

```
SELECT sin, Visit, Birth FROM dbo.Visit WHERE sin = xxxxxxx
```

In this case, because `Birth` is not included in your index, the Query Engine would create a plan that only accessed the main table - the reason is that it is simpler to scan the table once to get ALL the columns rather than going to the index, getting the `sin` and `Visit` values from there along with the ID of the row in the main table and then for each row go to that ID and get the additional `Birth` column value.  Far less efficient.

If I understand your question correctly then you need to include only the columns that define the index as part of your query - but it does not make sense to try and query the contents of an index.

Comment: Well please clarify it then

Comment: Martin correct, you do not understand my question.  ...

it is only about looking under the hood into the contents of the black box that is the data that supports the index ... think of that as a little bit like picking through a memory dump.

Comment: P.S.  Martin, regardless, i appreciate you for your effort; thank you.

Comment: Martin, you mentioned "index pages" ... they may be likely closely connected to my goal.

Comment: This will give you some pointers in that direction  https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2019-new-dmf-sys-dm_db_page_info/

Answer (score 0):

You can look under the hood if you want to, the key to this is `DBCC PAGE`.

Short introduction to use it.

Step1: you retrieve the indexes located on a table and it's index

```
SELECT
 name AS index_Name,
 index_id,
 type_desc  As index_Type,
 is_unique,
 OBJECT_NAME(object_id) As table_name
FROM
 sys.indexes
WHERE
 is_hypothetical = 0 AND
 index_id != 0 AND
 object_id = OBJECT_ID('<table name>');
```

Step 2: Retrieve the data page for this index

```
SELECT allocated_page_page_id
    ,next_page_page_id
    ,previous_page_page_id
    ,page_level
  ,page_type_desc
FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(db_id(), object_id('<table name>'), <index_id previous select>, NULL, 'DETAILED')
WHERE page_type_desc IS NOT NULL
    AND page_type_desc = 'INDEX_PAGE'
```

Step 3: now you know all pages used by the index.
For each page you can now select the actual data + Page and buffer data
For example, 1 of the allocated_page_page_id's is 18016
Showing the actual data you can do like this.

```
DBCC PAGE(webframe_v2, 1, 18016, 3) WITH TABLERESULTS
```

Comment: With the caveat that both sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations and DBCC PAGE are undocumented and at your own risk.   From SQL Server 2019 onwards sys.dm_db_page_info is the correct supported approach.

Comment: True, but the used SQL Server version was not specified by OP. And sys.dm_db_page_info is only supported since mssql2019, so a more general answer was justified.

Comment: Totally valid - just good to have the undocumented part explicit so anyone referring to it is properly warned.

Comment: thank you Kevin and Martin ... i will review; likely i will have follow-up questions—this looks like it does answer my question..